# Python benchmark: Why for in loop is faster than simple while?

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking

I was trying to optimize simple character counting function. After few changes I decided to check the timings and expected the function using basic 'while' loop to be faster than 'for in' loop.

But to my surprise while loop was almost 30% slower than for in here! Shouldn't be simple 'while' loop which has lower abstraction (doing less internally) be much faster than 'for in'?

```
import timeit

def faster_count_alphabet(filename):
    l = [0] * 128 # all ascii values 0 to 127
    with open(filename) as fh:
        a = fh.read()
        for chars in a:
            l[ord(chars)] += 1
    return l

def faster_count_alphabet2(filename):
    l = [0] * 128 # all ascii values 0 to 127
    with open(filename) as fh:
        a = fh.read()
        i = 0
        size = len(a)
        while(i<size):
            l[ord(a[i])] += 1
            i+=1
    return l

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print timeit.timeit("faster_count_alphabet('connect.log')", setup="from __main__ import faster_count_alphabet", number = 10)
    print timeit.timeit("faster_count_alphabet2('connect.log')", setup="from __main__ import faster_count_alphabet2", number = 10)
```

Here is the timings I am getting:

```
7.087787236
9.9472761879
```

Comment: for loop is highly optimised in python with C implementation, in the while loop the interpreter does more work

Comment: Even on optimizing in some way the for in must have to do all the same stuffs while is doing but also check the iterability of the variable, and much more right?

Comment: you could use comprehension, that works faster than for and while

Answer (score 0):

**While Loop**

Well in your while loop the interpreter has to check every iteration whether your expression is true therefore it has to access both elements i and size and compare them.

**For Loop**

The for loop on the other hand has no need for that since the for loop is optimized as Chris_Rands already pointed out

Comment: The explanation for the for loop isn't quite good. Obviously the for in loop hasn't got two variables to access and therefore no variables to compare which alone makes it slightly faster. Then another point is that python focuses the for in loop and therefore it is indeed the best optimized.

Comment: Does not 'for' also must check the bound somehow to stop at some point in iteration? Along with all the basic stuffs that while is doing, it also must somehow has to check the iterability of the variable and other properties which makes it smarter and shorter in syntax?

Comment: Haven't quite looked into how the for loop actually works since i just started python a few month ago but often for in loops are using simple iterators on which you can call next of course they know if they reached the end. For example like a linked list: each element has a value next and if that value is None you reached the end. If you want i find out how exactly the for loop works if no one else knows and shares. But all in all the for in loop will, when only iterating through the list, be faster than the while loop since the for in loop doesn't have multiple variables to access and compare

Comment: Another thing: Your code has a little mistake. You are not comparing the speed of the while and the for loop you are comparing the functions. one of the functions creates a variable 'size' and measures the length of 'a' and that also costs more time. just a little but it increases the time

Answer (score 0):

There are the result of my testing with python2.7:

**For Loop**

test1

```
python -mtimeit -s"d='/Users/xuejiang/go/src/main'.split('/')" "for i in range(len(d)):k=('index:',i,'value:',d[i])"
```

result:

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.747 usec per loop
```

test2:

```
python -mtimeit -s"d='/Users/xuejiang/go/src/main'.split('/');i=0" "for v in d:k=('index:',i,'value:',v);i+=1"
```

result:

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.524 usec per loop
```

**While Loop**

test

```
python -mtimeit -s"d='/Users/xuejiang/go/src/main'.split('/');i=0" "while i <len(d):k=('index:',i,'value:',d[i]);i+=1"
```

result:

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0658 usec per loop
```

That is: while loop is much faster

Answer (score 0):

Your code should represent same functionality, I have modified it for you to re-run your test.

I can see you even use the optimised version of the foreach loop instead of the normal for loop while you are benchmarking.

```
def faster_count_for_loop(filename):
l = [0] * 128 # all ascii values 0 to 127
with open(filename) as fh:
    a = fh.read()
    size = len(a)
    for i in range(size):
        l[ord(a[i])] += 1
return l

def faster_count_while_loop(filename):
l = [0] * 128 # all ascii values 0 to 127
with open(filename) as fh:
    a = fh.read()
    i = 0
    size = len(a)
    while(i < size):
        l[ord(a[i])] += 1
        i += 1
return l
```